# JS Callback Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a series of jQuery functions to execute in a block.  When they ALL are done, I need another function to be called.  It seems a callback is the best way to do this.  Here is my code.

```
 function flipPage (x, callback) {

    $("#view-1").animate({
    width: x,
    }, 500);
  $("#view-2").animate({
    width: browserWidth - x,
    }, 500);
  $("#iframe-2").animate({
    left:   -x,
    }, 500);
  $("#sweeper").animate({
    left:   x,
    }, 500);

  callback(function() {
    alert("I'm Done.");
    //do the next thing
  }) ;
}
```

Comment: It does not work.  I get Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: How are you calling `flipPage`?

Comment: Why are you passing all those empty functions to `.animate()`?

Comment: Good question on the empty functions.  My bad.  Removed.  I'm calling flipPage as flipPage(20);

Comment: @JonPaulBerti: There's your problem!  You aren't passing in anything for `callback`, so it's `undefined`... which is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the same as sjkm's, but simplified.

```
function flipPage (x, callback) {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#view-1").animate({
        width: x,
    }, 500, finished);

    $("#view-2").animate({
        width: browserWidth - x,
    }, 500, finished);

    $("#iframe-2").animate({
        left:   -x,
    }, 500, finished);

    $("#sweeper").animate({
        left:   x,
    }, 500, finished);

    function finished() {
        counter++;      
        if (counter >= 4) {
            alert("I'm Done.");
            //do the next thing if callback exists
            callback && callback.call();          
        }
    };
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kem6G/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
function flipPage (x, callback) {
      var animationHelper = {
        actionCounter: 0,
        actionCount: 4,
        callbackHandler: function() {
            this.actionCounter++;
            if(this.actionCounter == this.actionCount)
                this.callbackAllFinished();
        },
        callbackAllFinished: null
      };

      $("#view-1").animate({
        width: x }, 500, animationHelper.callbackHandler);

      $("#view-2").animate({
        width: browserWidth - x }, 500, animationHelper.callbackHandler);

      $("#iframe-2").animate({
        left: -x }, 500, animationHelper.callbackHandler);

      $("#sweeper").animate({
        left: x }, 500, animationHelper.callbackHandler);

      animationHelper.callbackAllFinished = function() {
        alert("I'm Done.");
        //do the next thing
      };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sjkm.  Can anyone offer a more simple example solution?